# Programming external QSPI flash Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: arm

I want to reprogram the external flash of a raspberry Pico via SWD line. This feature must be implemented in a different microcontroller, not from a Linux computer so the OpenOCD library cannot be used.

I already wrote a C library that is able to read and write in RAM and in core registers via SWD and I'm able to put the Cortex-M0+ into halt state.

I read many tutorials and documentation and those that are useful are:

- http://markding.github.io/swd_programing_sram/
- https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an0062.pdf
- https://community.silabs.com/s/article/how-to-program-internal-sram-over-swd?language=en_US

but unfortunately they aren't clear enough.

Can you explain the sequence of commands that I should send to RP2040 to correctly upload the new firmware?
Should I use bootrom functions to implement this operation? How can I call them?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you looked at the relevant code in openocd for the Pico? I've not, but it is not uncommon to load a small piece of code that handles the flash reading/writing. If openocd can do it, then life the code fragment that it downloads and/or simply mimic the methods it uses as you code will have to do much the same.

Comment: openocd writes the memory with [this function](https://github.com/raspberrypi/openocd/blob/rp2040/src/flash/nor/rp2040.c#L206), but I don't understand which registers it uses and what it writes into them

Comment: looks like it calls the bootrom functions via a trampoline. https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/26653ea81e340cacee55025d110c3e014a252a87/src/common/boot_picoboot/include/boot/picoboot.h

You'll have to do a bit of digging - I only found this with a cursory search

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but note that J-Flash and Keil both seem to support external flash on the Pico: https://www.segger.com/news/segger-j-link-flasher-and-embedded-studio-now-support-raspberry-pi-rp2040/ , https://github.com/GorgonMeducer/Pico_Template